# Python executes one 'for' loop but not the second

Tags: python, http, for-loop, beautifulsoup

My python code executes the first 'for' loop, but not the second.  If I comment out the first for loop, the second executes properly.

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from bs4 import NavigableString

site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/')
html = site.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.body.children

for item in tags:        
    print (item.name)
    print (item.attrs)

for item in tags:
    if ('role' in item.attrs and item.attrs['role'] == 'banner'):
        print (item)
    else: pass
```

any ideas?  My IDLE gui is acting strange tonight (shift+indent is indenting instead of undenting for example) so if this works for everyone else properly it might just be my box.

Thanks community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used BeautifulSoup, but it sounds a lot like `tags` is an iterator, not a list or something similar. That means, `iter(tags) is tags` and it has state that is altered by `next()`. As a consequence, iterating over it consumes it irreparably. I'd also wager that `body.children` is a property that creates a new iterator on each access, so you can run both loops if you turn it into a list first, or repeat `tags = soup.body.children` after the first loop.

Comment: The simplest solution, redefining tags, worked.  The most efficient, creating a list from tags, also works.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tags` is an iterable, but not a sequence; the first `for` loop exhausts the iterable, leaving no elements for the second. Pass it to the `list` or `tuple` constructor to create a sequence from it, then iterate over that.